# Comparing strings with dynamic value of one word in Python

Tags: python

I have an application that parses a file and inserts it into DB. If insert failes user is presented with error list as in example:

1. Line 1: Error creating field test, duplicated
2. Line 4: Error user does not exist
3. Line 8: Error creating field name, duplicated
4. Line 10: Error user does not exist

I wrote a test in Selenium that creates Jira ticket for the errors. I managed to make it create single Jira ticket for points 2 and 4, as the error Is exactly the same but I end up with 2 separate tickets created for points 1 and 3, these are also the same errors but for different fields. The question is how to achieve this?
Now I use code like this:

```
errorElements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'red')

if errorElements:
    errors_list = []
    users_list = []
    for i in errorElements:
        user = i.text[i.text.find("username") + 9::].split()[0]
        error = i.text[i.text.find(": ")::]
        if errors_list.count(error) == 1:
            users_list[errors_list.index(error)] = f"{users_list[errors_list.index(error)]}, {user}"
        else:
          users_list.append(user)
          errors_list.append(error)

    final_list = list(zip(users_list,errors_list))
    create_jira_issue(final_list, path, driver.current_url, summary)
```

Which of course fails to accomplish the goal for points 1 nad 3 of the example.

Comment: Do errorElements have error code (numerical values) which correspond to the type of error? If so can you use such a field to group your errors?

Comment: No, they don't as a matter of fact they are all returned as HTTP 400 regardless of the error message.